# How can I connect my new light fixtures to old fluorescent fixture bases?

Tags: kitchens, led, light

I have these old 6 inch recessed fluorescent light cans in my kitchen. I can hardly find the bulbs anywhere so I decided to replace them.

[image]

I pulled them apart thinking a could simply wire a new fixture, but it's not as easy as I thought. I purchased the LED retrofit, but it seems to assume I have a standard bulb socket. I don't have a bulb socket but the old can is attached to the black and white wire coming out of the wall.  How do I get this apart and then can I connect the black and white wires to the new retrofit LED?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Cut off the light bulb adapter, strip the wires, cut off (or release, if they are releasable - look for a hole to poke something into) the plastic connector blocks, strip those wires if you had to cut them off,  and wirenut black to black and white to white. Keep the little orange connector, it's handy for removing the light later, and for being able to wire the connections without the light being in your face.

Comment: ok thank you, that is what I thought but wasn't sure. makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Those retrofit kits are designed to be wired one of two ways.   Either screw the fitting into an existing Edison base... Or snip off and discard the Edison end and direct-wire from there.

Either way, keep the rather convenient disconnect plug.  They are mandatory in hardwired fluorescents and will probably be soon mandatory in this type of installation.   If you want more like that, they are under a buck at the local big box.  I fit them regardless, because they are convenient.

Those stab-blocks are 3-way splices between the supply and the two ballasts.  You can tease out the supply wire by pulling and twisting.  The stab-block can only be used once, those are done.

I am not a fan of stab blocks, and recommend either wire nuts (I'm guessing orange is a good size) or clamp style splice blocks which are reusable. The screw-down style Euro blocks are also fine.

Make sure you permanently disconnect the ballasts.